# update-in with regex causing NullPointerException

Tags: clojure

I have the following functions and reduced sample:

```
(defn parse-time
  [time-str] 
  (->> time-str
       (re-find #"(\d{1,2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})")
       ...))

(defn coerce-times
  [m & ks]
  (update-in m ks parse-time))

(coerce-times {:depart "05:05:00" :arrive "05:05:00"} :depart :arrive)
```

This works as expected with only one key, but when I try to use multiple keys (as in the example above), I get a NPE. Line 20 is the `re-find` line.:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at java.util.regex.Matcher.getTextLength (Matcher.java:1234)
    java.util.regex.Matcher.reset (Matcher.java:308)
    java.util.regex.Matcher.<init> (Matcher.java:228)
    java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher (Pattern.java:1088)
    clojure.core$re_matcher.invoke (core.clj:4460)
    clojure.core$re_find.invoke (core.clj:4512)
    tempest.core$parse_time.invoke (core.clj:20)
    ...
```

Can someone please help me understand what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keys vector provided to update-in is not a collection of keys to operate on, but a series of lookups to follow:

```
user> (update-in {:a {:b {:c 0}}} [:a :b :c] inc)
{:a {:b {:c 1}}}
```

Comment: Completely flew over my head; it's time to take a break. Thanks!

Comment: @CaesiumFarmer If this answer solved your problem, you should "accept" it by clicking the check-mark next to its vote box.